# Where can I ask this question about writing a character that tries to overcome a disability?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about a psychological topic, but it is also about a fictional character in the story I’m writing. I posted the question to psychology first. But it was closed for being unfocused, and I was recommended to post it in writing instead. So I edited the question to narrow it down, and posted the edited version in writing. But that was closed for being off topic. It was moved to psychology, but then it was still closed. The original one in psychology has not yet been reopened after I edited it. If not psychologically or writing, I’m not sure where I can ask this question. Can someone please advise me where to go? Is there a different site I should try?

Here's the question title and body:

> **Title**: Would a mute person be able to speak again?
>
> I'm writing a story. I have a character who is mute and has been mute for over 10 years. I want to know how likely it would be for him to start speaking again and what that would realistically be like.
> I'll try to explain the background briefly. This story takes place in a different time period, by the way. He was fairly poor. Other than that, he had a pretty normal life growing up. Until one day when he was 12 he got caught breaking a law with some other kids and he had to run away to escape. He ran away from home and joined a gang of outlaws since he couldn't go back. Not long after he joined them, he made a mistake and basically something he said caused them all to nearly get caught. The leader was furious and threatened to kill him if he ever spoke another word again. So he stopped speaking and became mute from then on. He lived with this gang for over 10 years. Now, roughly 10-15 years later, he left and got out of that life. He now has new friends, people who care about him and who he trusts, and he is trying to start living a normal life again. So that's what's going on with this character.
>
> Now for my question: How likely is it for someone in this scenario to start speaking again?
>
> I want the psychological experience of this character to be realistic and to make sense, so any information on the topic would be appreciated.

Comment: [I commented on your question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/199719/would-a-mute-person-be-able-to-speak-again#comment619119_199719) while it was (briefly) on Worldbuilding. IMO, Psychology would have been the correct site. Yet, they felt it wasn't. Given that, I suggest you reword your question to [make it on-topic for that site](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Perhaps focus on finding case studies of similar conditions.

Comment: You might want to start with deciding which specific [type of mutism](https://www.speechpathologygraduateprograms.org/mutism/) your character has and then look up information on that.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't sound like it fit perfectly on any site. This is what I know and think about your question:

- it is currently off-topic on [Writing SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/). This I am 100% confident about being an active user there.
- it may work on [Worldbuilding SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/), but you would need to broaden the scope of the question, check out their [help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) first. You could try rephrasing it to "how would someone emotionally and physically traumatized start talking again?". This I am not *fully* confident about, try looking through their help pages and raising a question on [Worldbuilding Meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/) first.
- you could retry [Psychology SE](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/), but I don't think it would work there because there isn't a ton of info on your question. See Bryan Krause's answer. Look at their [help pages](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/) too. This I have am not very confident about, not being a member of their community.

Comment: A lot of times "how would a character do X" is off-topic on WB as it's too story-based. As the name of the stack suggests, questions should be about *building a world*. Questions about characters work if they are applicable to the world at large. Like, "How would a vampire do X" when it means "The vampires in the world" rather than "this specific one in the story".

Comment: @VLAZ That's what I assumed. Would a rephrasing of the question, like "how would someone emotionally and physically traumatized start talking again?" work on worldbuilding as it would apply to more people than "how would this specific character recover"?

Comment: Not sure it would. At its core, it's not about a world. The problem is that such conditions are psychological in nature and highly related to each person. There isn't a formula to apply or some rule of thumb to follow to say "Yeah, Alice just needs to do X and Y and she'll talk again in approximately 6-8 weeks". Compare with, say, flu or other diseases which can be generalised like that. My suggestion was to look into cases of people going mute due to psychological factors. Possibly other speech issues stemming to social environment can also be helpful. Cases like this exist IRL and have been

Comment: treated with varying degrees of success. It would be a very useful research material. For writing a story, it doesn't even matter how *precisely* a character would recover in the medical sense. Case studies can demonstrate what behaviour real people have exhibited, issues they've had and treatments they've received. These are elements that can be included in the story to flesh it out and make it believable. In the end a story needs to be believable, rather than written from a manual. And ironically, to me it seems like [psychology.se] is the place to ask for such case studies.

Answer (score 0):

There may not be any SE site that fits your question.

For Psychology, an answer would be expected to be based on actual scientific evidence. You'd need to study real people in the circumstances you describe. This is a study population that is highly unlikely to exist in the real world.